# Unity/vuforia imagetarget - object not showing properly

Tags: unity, vuforia

I learn it from vuforia tutorial on youtube.

I add a white cube(or sphere) as the child of image target.

When the camera catches the image target, the screen turns to be totally white. It seems that the object target is too large to show on screen.

When I move away from the image target, the camera works again. I tried a new project and repeated my steps many times, and I do succeed sometimes. I don't why most times it just shows part of object and fills all screen.

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to know whether my answer did help you or not :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be, that your camera "Clipping Planes" are not set up correctly. For most image targets you have to increase the "far" field. I set the far field most of the times to 10000 and everything works fine.

[image]

I hope, that that can fix your problems :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have pre-set the scale correctly. If necessary, please set the scale in your code.